# How we can run only selected code in loop with imacro

Tags: macros, imacros

```
VERSION BUILD=10022823
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !LOOP 2
URL GOTO=example.com

WAIT SECONDS=5
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:columns<SP>medium-5 EXTRACT=TXT
SET !CLIPBOARD {{!EXTRACT}}
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=*  FILE={{!CLIPBOARD}}_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} 
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:PDF CONTENT=EVENT:SAVETARGETAS
WAIT SECONDS=10


TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>Out&&HREF:example.com/logout
```

Now I want to run lines in between `WAIT SECONDS=5` to `WAIT SECONDS=10` 10 times in single loop, then after that run last line `TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>Out&&HREF:example.com/logout`

How it is possible.

I am using imacro 10v.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the JavaScript to accomplish this..try the below code

```
iimPlay("CODE:URL GOTO=example.com");

for (var i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
iimPlay("CODE:WAIT SECONDS=5\n TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:columns<SP>medium-5 EXTRACT=TXT");
var extract = iimGetLastExtract();
iimSet("extract",extract);
iimPlay("CODE:ADD !EXTRACT {{extract}}\n SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FILE=Extract_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} 
}
iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Sign<SP>Out&&HREF:example.com/logout");
```